# How to temporarily enchant weapons with magic effects?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic-items

In Final Fantasy series there's a job called [*Mystic Knight*](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Mystic_Knight) (a.k.a. *Spell Fencer*, *Rune Fencer*), where you can temporarily enchant your weapon with a Spell you know (from Black Mage spell table) called *Spellblade*.

In Final Fantasy 5 for e.g., a Spellblade takes a turn (it's an action) and after that, those are the effects:

- Fire/Blizzard/Thunder/Poison: 2x damage when striking an elemental weakness
- Fira/Blizzara/Thundara: 3x damage when striking an elemental weakness

[...and so on](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Mystic_Knight_(Final_Fantasy_V)).

In practical 5e, looks a multi class of Fighter/Paladin and Wizard/Warlock. I'd like to know if there's any way of recreating this kind of effect on 5e without Homebrew.

The only spell I found which looks like it is Magic Weapon (*2nd-level transmutation*, for Paladins and Wizards):

> You touch a nonmagical weapon. Until the spell ends that weapon becomes a magic weapon with a +1 bonus to attack and damage rolls.

You can't add any element (nor do any extra damage based off that), only plusses. It's a basic version of what a Mystic Knight would do. All other enchanting spells are meant for permanent enchant.

Is there any other Spell which fits this behavior in any other book other than PHB/DMG?

If not, how to Homebrew it in a balanced way? *(Example: Adds 1d4 magical damage of an element? Doesn't add but does critical damage only on who has weakness? What could be replacement for Fire/Blizzard/Thunder/Poison in 5e? etc)*

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for the *Elemental Weapon* spell. It's a  3rd level spell available only to Paladins, and it's on page 237 of the PHB. It allows you to enchant your weapon to deal 1d4 damage of a type of your choice for the next hour.

Comment: While the spell requirement is quite high (_3rd level_) and Paladin-only, it indeed does the trick. Thank you!

Comment: @RaphaelDDL Yeah, it's not very powerful for a 3rd-level spell, unfortunately, especially since Paladins only get 3rd-level spells at level 9. A Bard could use Magical Secrets to get it (in case that helps you). Also, Spell Fencer + Dark Knight FTW (not really relevant but I wanted to say it).

Comment: It's worth pointing out that while Elemental Weapon isn’t that great, you’ve omitted that it also turns the weapon into a +1 Weapon so it’s slightly better than what is mentioned here.

Answer (score 3):

I believe what you're looking for is basicaly built into various classes instead of them being spells.

- The Eldritch Knight (Fighter) is basically the pure form of FF's Mystic Knight. Arcane Archer (Fighter) has magical abilities and the arrows are considered magical when shot.
- Clerics may (depending on domain) infuse their weapons with energy gaining extra damage dices, paladins do something similar.
- A Monk's Ki-Empowered Strikes makes the attacks considered magical and *Way of the 4 Elements/Way of the Kensei* might be interesting to you.
- A 3rd level Horizon Walker (Ranger) turns weapon damage type into force damage.

If you're only interested in spells that might fit a mystic Knight these are worth to look at:

1. Absorb Elements
2. Hail of Thorns
3. Zephyr Strike
4. Booming Blade
5. Lightning Lure
6. Shadow Blade
7. Green-Flame Blade
8. Sword Burst
9. Thunderwave
10. Cloud of Daggers
11. Maximillian's Earthen Grasp
12. Hellish Rebuke

As one can see without using homebrew options various combinations can be used to gain a similar result as FF's Mystic Knight. You can also take the *Magic Initiate* feat to 'steal' spells known from a different spell list (This is the reason my list is a mix from various spell lists). Sadly as some classes have no cantrips (like Ranger) you might need to pick that as main class to build upon.

Same (or even better) result can be gained from some class features like a warlock's Book of Shadows (Pact of the Tome):

> Your patron gives you a grimoire called a Book of Shadows. When you gain this feature, choose three cantrips from any class's spell list (the three needn't be from the same list). While the book is on your person, you can cast those cantrips at will. They don't count against your number of cantrips known. If they don't appear on the warlock spell list, they are nonetheless warlock spells for you.

I can see a pure Eldritch Knight or Warlock (Hexblade) do well as a 'Mystic Knight' picking some nice extra spells with Magic Initiate. If you consider multiclassing the above listed classes like the Monk (Way of the Kensei) or even a Paladin (Oath of Conquest?) can create a crazy character build.

Comment: How does Thunderwave fit the "enchant a weapon" motif?

Comment: @KorvinStarmast It is a mass attack spell and one can flavor it something like pointing a trident at the enemies or slamming a maul into the ground when the waves appear. I admit it is a bit out of the 'Norm' but consider it as a flood-summon/water element weapon attack

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the [Magic Weapon](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/magic-weapon) and [Elemental Weapon](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/elemental-weapon) spells already mentioned, the [Mystic class from Unearthed Arcana](https://media.wizards.com/2017/dnd/downloads/UAMystic3.pdf) also has an Immortal Discipline titled "Psionic Weapon".

One of the things Psionic Weapon lets you do is spend 5 psi points to use Augmented Weapon:

> ***Augmented Weapon (5 psi; conc., 10 min.).*** As a bonus action, touch one simple or martial weapon. Until your concentration ends, that weapon becomes a magic weapon with a +3 bonus to its attack and damage rolls.

Note that the Mystic doesn't have to use this on their own weapon; they can also do so on an ally's weapon instead. (That said, they can only concentrate on one thing at a time.)

Answer (score -2):

In a home brew game I created a spell that does X/elemental damage as an enchant equipment spell. I use spell points as a base for casting the spell, rather than levels. This is a spell designed to use inner focus from caster requiring an innate ability to cast magic in raw energy form.  As an effect that energy is created and formed into one element. Air, fire, earth, water,cold,lightning, spirit, etc.  Once created the energy can then be used to enchant an item for 1 attack:  sword, arrow, lance, rock, stick.  Rather than using levels to cast the spell they are used as damage modifiers.  This spell has no duration only an effect and damage.

- formula for spell is as follows.

  You spend spell points from your magic pool, which is based on a single stat(Int/Cha/Wis).  The player has Int 15 with mod +2 and is level 3. Magic pool is base 5 sp +2 per level, so sp total is 11.  Now at level 3 the spell cost 6 sp to cast. The spell does 1d6 fire damage; the spell cast modifier of 2 int x level 3
- Example of applying the formula
  I rolled a 1d6 die and get a 4, 4+2=6X3=18fire damage on successful hit with enchanted item. The the magic is gone.  On a fumbled spell check nothing happens however you still burn spell points in attempting to cast the spell DM discretion how this effects your character.
  Also the weapon or item you are trying to enchant is generally broken or destroyed.
  These restrictions apply to all levels of the spell.

  I personally cap this spell at seventh level due to the fact my homebrew group is a multiverse campaign level 5 is best for standard D&D games.

Comment: please edit your post to improve its punctuation, structuring and readability - right now, it's not very helpful, due to being so hard to read.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! I tried to improve the formatting and punctuation. Markdown can be a bit weird, but there is a help box at the top of the box where you type that you should use to format the result so that it's easy to read. I think you are basing this design on the optional spell points, but I don't know what you mean for example with the *instant spell* and the *one strike spell*. These are not normal terms for D&D 5e. Where did you find them? And why did you choose to cap at level 7 spells? Most of the time the cap is at level 5, like with the *Ring of Spell Storin*.

Comment: In the middle of your text you also switch to MP, which is a normal term for many videogames I've played, but has no meaning in D&D 5e. Could you please [edit] your answer to elaborate what you mean, where you took the inspiration for this method and how it works out in your games? If you have a moment please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about the site. Have fun!

Comment: Does sp = Spell Points in your second sentence?

Comment: OK, having just tried to put your answer into a readable format, how did I do?  Edit it again please if I somehow missed what you were getting at.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast The problem here isn't the format alone, the original poster/asker mentioned this: "I'd like to know if there's any way of recreating this kind of effect on 5e without Homebrew. " As such no reply about homebrew is an answer in my opinion.

Comment: @Drake Question includes "how to homebrew in a balanced way" in the first sentence of the last paragraph,  however, there's a lot that needs to be adjusted for this question to better answer the question.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast True